# Angluar2 routing inside http interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I use Angular 2.4.8. Communication with backend is via REST. In each request I need to send `X-Auth-Token` in header. The token is stored on session. When token is outdated server returns 401 status. In such a case I want application to go to login page.

I added http interceptor to my project

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

    constructor(backend: XHRBackend
        , defaultOptions: RequestOptions
        , private router: Router
    ) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.request(url, options).catch((error: Response) => {
            if ((error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) && 
            (window.location.href.match(/\?/g) || []).length < 2) {
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
                console.log('The authentication session expires.');
                window.sessionStorage.removeItem('auth-token');
                window.location.href = window.location.href + '/login';
                // this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.empty();
            }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
    }
}
```

and it works well except. But I don't use router but plain redirect and whole application reloads. When I changed commenting to

```
// window.location.href = window.location.href + '/login';
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

the app doesn't follow the link. How to make router to work (navigate)?

**edit 2018-01-22**

My `app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        resolve: {
            boolean: InitResolverService
        }
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'system'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            routes
            // , { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

where in `InitResolverService` I have some logic to do on first navigation and then emit `true` and complete stream.

And `LoginComponent`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login.component.less']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    private username: FormControl;
    private password: FormControl;
    public form: FormGroup;
    public displayDialog = false;
    isLoginButtonEnabled = true;
    isResetButtonVisible = false;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private initService: InitResolverService
    ) {
        this.username = new FormControl(Validators.required);
        this.password = new FormControl(Validators.required);
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            Username: this.username,
            Password: this.password
        });
        this.form.setValue({
            Username: '',
            Password: ''
        });
        this.displayDialog = true;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initService.showSplash();
        this.authService.canActivate(this.route.snapshot, this.router.routerState.snapshot).subscribe(x => {
            if (x) {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `/login` URL in your router configuration?

Comment: Could you publish console errors, when app is trying redirect?

Comment: Can you create a plunker with this?

Comment: @AlexParamonov Yes.

Comment: @JaroslawK.No errors in console except network errors with 401.

Comment: can you share your app-routng.module?

Comment: @brijmcq I edited the question.

Comment: @koral can you show your login.component too? I want to know if you are calling a service from there.

Comment: @brijmcq Added in question but this is not the most current version - it is stripped from some code I can't publish. Which service do you mean?

Comment: @koral it was just a hunch that you might be calling some protected end point in your login.component that's why you are having a 401 error as you mentioned above, which you may already know as Unauthorized error

Comment: @koral is it possible for you to update your angular to v4 or 5?

Answer (score 5):

we are solve this case with write own custom http-service that we using all http request via REST.

Also you can with custom http-service;

- central api path
- create header with token
- handle all HTTP err result even 401

Simple code sample

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

export const API_PATH = "http://apipath"

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpService {

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        public router: Router) { }

    headerWithToken(): Headers {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Authorization', 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('TOKEN'));
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return headers;
    }

    get(params: URLSearchParams, method: string): Observable<any> {
        const url = `${API_PATH}/${method}`;
        return this.http.get(url, {params: params, headers: this.headerWithToken()})
        .map(
            res => <Array<any>>res.json()
        )
        .catch(err => {
            const result = this.handleErrors(err, this);
            return result;
        });
    }

    // put same way

    // post same way

    // delete same way

    public handleErrors(error: Response, obj: any): ErrorObservable {
        const errData = error.json();
        if (error.status === 401) {
            obj.router.navigate(['/login']);
        } else if (errData.message) {
            // give a message or something
        } else {
            console.log(errData);
        }
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does `obj.router` come from?

Comment: i have edited answer. I forgot add router dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't use interceptor for that. with every API call I use `.catch` to catch errors and pass to this function:

```
  // define the error handler in a separate method so we can reuse it 
  //in other methods
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    console.error('ApiService::handleError', error);
    if (error.status === 401) {
      this.oAuthService.logOut();
    }
   return Observable.throw(error);
  }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution since you have to repeat that logic everywhere

Comment: I used it in my `ApiService` similar to answer above by Tanser Çobanoğlu.  yes, you need to add `.catch(this.handleError);` after each api call, but you probably do it anyway to catch and throw any errors. Interceptor will also be good way but it's not at necessarily better

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor( public auth: AuthenticationService,
               private router: Router ) {
  } 

  public intercept( request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let url: string = request.url;
    let method: string = request.method;
    console.log(`JwtInterceptor url=${url},   method=${method}`);

    return next.handle( request ).do( ( event: HttpEvent<any> ) => {
        console.log(`successful reply from the server for request=${request.urlWithParams}`);
    })
    .catch((responseError: any) => {

      // ResponseError Interceptor
      if (responseError instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.error('response in the catch: ', responseError);

          if ( responseError.status === 401 ) {
            let errorMsg: string = '';

            if ( responseError.statusText === 'Invalid credentials' ) {
              errorMsg = 'Username or password is incorrect';
            }

            // redirect to the login route
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {msg: errorMsg}});
            return empty();
          }

        return throwError(responseError);
      }


      let error = new HttpErrorResponse({
        status: 500,
        statusText: 'Unknown Error',
        error: {
          message: 'Unknown Error'
        }
      });
      return throwError( error );

    }) as any;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at your app.module.ts you should add:

```
{provide : Http, useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) => new HttpInterceptor(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router),deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]}
```

at your HttpInterceptor:

```
 constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _router: Router) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }
```

Comment: Now I have error during compilation: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 108:25 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in C:/angular-app/src/app/app.module.ts. Line 108 is where I put `useFactory`

Comment: make function--------    export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions,
  router: Router) {
  return new HttpService(backend, options, router);
} -------- and add this function to the providers to solve the problem -------- {
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: httpFactory,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
    }