# How to correctly implement a HTTP Interceptor in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to redirect the user to login when the http status code from the request is 401. But following the instructions of many sites the catchError isn't working.

This is my actual code.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

                console.log('OK test');

                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    // OK
                }
                return event;
            }), catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

                console.log('non-OK test');

                if (error.status === 401) {
                    LocalStorageService.deslogar();
                    this.router.navigate(['/autenticacao/login']);
                } else if (error.status === 403) {
                    // Forbidden
                } else if (error.status === 404) {
                    // Not Found
                }
                return throwError(error);
            }));
    }
```

And his result:

[image]

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764322/angular-interceptor-route-to-a-different-path-based-on-response

Answer (score 0):

As referred in the comment above you should not throw an error in the redirect case.
Returning an `empty()` observable in these cases should do the trick.

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that the request return never enters the catchError block. Even if I put to return empty (), it doesn't work because this line of code is not reached.